# PS4 saved game data is lost after Restoring Default Settings (after power outage), but screenshots are still there

Tags: ps4

I suffered a power outage at home, facing the following problem hours after when trying to turn my PS4 Pro on (sorry, my PS4 language is set to Spanish, but I'm adding a translation with every screenshot):

***Translation***: Checking the system's storage status...Don't turn your PS4 off. When the check is over, your PS4 will reset automatically:
[image]

Then the following message appeared:

***Translation***: A serious error has occurred in the system software. The PS4 will restart
[image]

This process was triggered when I selected the fourth option here (Restore Default Settings):
[image]

Everything is back (surprisingly, even in-game screenshots!)... ***but the game saved data, which is gone***:

[image]

Is there any way to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you backup your saved games locally or use PS+ cloud storage (with or without auto-upload), it's gone. If you do backup your saves, you can transfer them back.

Comment: I suspect the data is still being there, somewhere. The screenshots are there, so the same should apply for the data. I guess there might be an option to restore it.

Comment: Doubtful, rebuilding the database probably destroyed the file pointers.

Comment: I didn't rebuild the database, but "Restore(d) Default Settings". You can see that if you read the question